# What are the limitations of HarshiCorp Vault Dynamic Secrets for Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-pod

I want to understand whether we can rotate keys for accessing a static key?

I mean if you think about Salesforce, Jenkins, Jira that support static keys, Passwords how to handle such with a key rotation strategy does such supported by HarshiCorp Vault?

Does the above requirement supported by Vault or its a limitation? Please share all the limitations if you are familiar with the product.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from official HarshiCorp Vault Discussion forum: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-create-dynamic-secrets-for-custom-applications-that-has-static-username-password/4606